# Is "were" natural here?

Tags: tense

> A woman is talking on the phone with her children. She hangs up. A man has overheard her conversation and asks: How were the kids?

Would that be natural? Would it be perfectly natural to use "were"?

Answer (score 1):

The whole paragraph is in the present tense, so I expected the question to be "How are the kids?".

That said, there is nothing wrong with "How were the kids?" or "How were they?" particularly if an event of the past is being discussed and you are asking about their mental/physical/emotional state at that point.

If you are just asking after them, "How are they?" or "How are they doing?" would suffice.